# Parse the contents of a webpage

Tags: javascript, parsing, html

I'm working on an `html` page for my department at work. Just `html` and `css` nothing fancy. Now, we are trying to get data from another webpage to be displayed in the new one we are working on. I assume that I would need to use `JavaScript` and a parser of some sort but I'm not sure how to do this or what really to search for.

The solution I assume would exist is to have a function, feed it a link of the webpage we want to mine, and it would return (for example) the number of times a certain word was repeated in that webpage.

Comment: Yes you need javascript for that. Also Is this other webpage on same domain ?

Comment: Yup. I believe it is on the same domain. Any example on how to do that with JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to go for it is by using node.js and then installing cheerio (parser) and request (http request) module. There are many detailed tutorials showing how to do this (for e.g. [this one at digital ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-node-js-request-and-cheerio-to-set-up-simple-web-scraping)).

But, if you don't want to have nodejs setup and want to work with plain web setup. Then, download cheerio and request js libraries and include them in your html page in  tag and then follow above example. I hope it helps.

Comment: I will look into cheerios. But I can't install npm.

Comment: what problem you facing while installing?

Comment: I can't install because I'm using corporate workstation which does not allow installing such libraries.